# I need to Remove this line <meta name='robots' content='noindex,follow' />

Tags: plugins

I am need to remove this line from home page our WordPress site

```
<meta name='robots' content='noindex,follow' />
```

but this code not a show any location.

you help ans this code show which location..

Answer (score 7):

This happens when you check that sneaky checkbox while installing WordPress:

> Discourage search engines from indexing this site

To disable it, simply head over to `Settings > Reading` and disable the above checkbox. If this is being added to your theme's header by a third party plugin, then it's not easy to answer.